# How measure distance between to objects using Camera in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I want to measure distance between two moving cars by using Camera of Iphone. How can this will be possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307940/measuring-distance-with-iphone-camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your Fingers.
It is possible if you have a setup where you know the distance between 2 points then use this as a ratio